# if a circle is deformation retract of a manifold; then is there a knot deformation retract to an embedded M in 3-space

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let M be a metric space such that the circle is deformation retract of M. If a circle is embedded in 3-space, we obtain a knot.  Suppose the space M is embedded in 3-space and its projection image in a plane has n crossing points.  Then is it true that there exists a knot K with n crossings such that K is deformation retract of the embedded M in 3-space.

I am thinking of the following case:  Let $S_1^1$ and $S_2^1$ be two disjoint circles and $l$ is an arc joining the two circles. Pick a point $x_2 \in S_2^1$ and define a topological space $M=S_1^1 \cup \{ S_2^1 \setminus x_2 \} \cup l $. The subspace $S_1^1$  is deformation retract of M. Suppose M is embedded in 3-space by only knotted the arc $l$. The circle $S_1^1$ and the punctured circle $S_2^1 \setminus x_2$ are kept standard.  Is the embedded M equivalent to some knot or there exists a knot K such that K is deformation retract of the embedded M.

Comment: I didn't know there were $1$ manifolds that deformation retracted onto circles that are not circles.

Comment: Take for example circle and punctured circle joined by an arc.  This is 1-manifold deformation retract of the circle but it is not a circle.

Comment: Every connected 1-manifold is homeomorphic to $S^1$, $(0,1)$, $[0,1]$, or $(0,1]$. Which of these is the one you describe?

Comment: The one I described is homotopic equivalent to $S^1$

Comment: How about wedge sum of two circles.  This is 1- manifold which is not homeomorphic to any of the spaced you mentioned.

Comment: That's not a manifold. Perhaps by "$1$-manifold" you mean "metric space of topological dimension $1$."

Comment: Sorry for this mistake,  I mean 1-metric space not a manifold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20628/discussion-between-user134875-and-matt-samuel).